# can anyone identify this programming language?

Tags: programming-languages

it's a secret message on a postcard. Please don't post the result, it would be nice if you could give a hint on how to find out what it is written in instead:

[image]

Comment: The answer by Mike below is the correct one. I just wanted you to know you have very mean friends lol

Comment: So far, two people didn't really read the question...

Comment: @Jeff, buddy, i dindn't tell him what is written, neither i posted the code, or told him how to decrypt in the blink of an eye. `how to find out what it is written`... now how do you translate a phrase from Spanish to English if i don't give you a paperback bilingual dictionary??? Once i give you the tool, is your job to match the words and make sense of the sentence...

Comment: @Carlos - he said what it is written *in*.

Answer (score 4):

Hope it helps!

[image: Command List]

[image: C reference List]